# onw of my two app is not working in django

Tags: django, django-apps

Below is my code. In my hello_world project there is two app pages. one is home page and another is profile page. home page is working fine, but profile page is showing error.

**hello_world urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('home_page.urls',)),
    path('profile_page',include('profile_page.urls',))
]
```

**home page urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',views.home,name='home page'),
]
```

**home page views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
def home(request):
    return HttpResponse('home page')
```

**profile page urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('profile_page',views.profile,name='profile page'),
]
```

**profile page views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
def profile(request):
    return HttpResponse('profile page')
```

Comment: Can you please show the error

Comment: Using the URLconf defined in hello_world.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
admin/
[name='home page']
profile_page admin/
profile_page profile_page [name='profile page']
The current path, profile_page/, didn’t match any of these.

Comment: Could you directly edit your question (instead of commenting) so that other people have all the information at once?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use redirect method and include view name space as an argument..

Find the updated code:
from django.http import HttpResponse
def profile(request):
return redirect('profile page')

Don't forgot to import redirect...

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of the path() function, i.e. the 'route' argument, must end with a forward slash.

```
path('profile_page/',include('profile_page.urls',))
```

Notice the forward slash at the end of the first argument, **'profile_page/'**.

Your URLconf is not matching the expected pattern because of the missing slash.